# SQL Server paging using limit and offset with non-unique ordering column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I would like to implement paging using SQL Server limit and offset as shown below. My question is, will SQL Server guerantee the correct data page when data is ordered by non-unique column?

```
SELECT * FROM TableName
ORDER BY NonUniqueColumn
OFFSET 10 ROWS
FETCH NEXT 20 ROWS ONLY
OPTION (recompile)

SELECT * FROM TableName
ORDER BY NonUniqueColumn
OFFSET 20 ROWS
FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY
OPTION (recompile)
```

These two selects overlap. Will the second select (second page) contain the last ten rows from the first select?

Comment: If the order keys are equal, the order of these equal rows is not guarranted. So if those happen to be at the page limits, they might appear in different order and pages, possibly. Add the PK as a second order criteria if the order is not unique to prevent this.

Comment: Did you test it before asking?

Comment: @Sami, yes I tried, it looks paging works, but I do not know if it works always.

Comment: @Alejandro Thank you, that is a solution. If you create an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> will SQL Server guerantee the correct data page when data is ordered by non-unique column?

No. Add the primary key columns to the ORDER BY to guarantee a stable ordering.  EG

```
SELECT * FROM TableName
ORDER BY NonUniqueColumn, Id
OFFSET 10 ROWS
FETCH NEXT 20 ROWS ONLY
OPTION (recompile)
```